# Why Jersey send a 403 status when an exception is not caught in my code?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am using Jersey to create REST services and when I get a NullPointerException or other type of RuntimeException a 403 error is sent to the client. Why Jersey sends 403 instead of a 500 and how can I change it?

PS: I know how to create an ExceptionMapper but it seems strange to create it to the RuntimeException class. I also use specific Exceptions extending WebApplicationException for the exceptions I am throwing.

Comment: Did you consider looking up what HTTP status 403 means? It doesn't have anything to do with exceptions in your code.

Comment: @EJP That's the point, I don't want this status. I want a 500, but when an exception occurs this is what I get.

Comment: This is not standard `Jersey` behaviour. Are you able to post a simple use case demonstrating this that we can test?

Comment: Hi @Will What I am doing is the same as posted by Tichodroma muraria. But in my case this is returning a 403. Is is a configuration?

Comment: @Joqus That cannot be all you're doing. You must be doing something else otherwise you'd get a `500`. Why don't you post more of your code - start with all your exception mappers and where you register them.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your problem. Calling this resource returns a 500:

```
@GET
@Path("/npe")
public Response triggerNpe() {
    String npe = null;
    npe.length();        
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am using Glassfish 4 with standard libraries.

Comment: Maybe it is a customization, do you know how can I check it?

Answer (score 0):

That should not happen. Your error is handled somewhere. 
Look these annotations:

- @ControllerAdvice
- @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
- @ExceptionHandler(YourException.class)